# Selective Canvas.ZIndex between two controls

Tags: wpf

I have two chart components. One is set a higher `Canvas.ZIndex` than the other. But, I want the axis of the chart with the higher `Canvas.ZIndex` to have a lower `Canvas.ZIndex` than the axis of the chart with the lower `Canvas.ZIndex`. The axis is expectedly in the subtree of the chart. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Adorner Layer, which is always above anything else, and made specifically for those situations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx

Comment: How does it help? Adorner is applied to one UI element. Meanwhile asker wishes next thing: when two UI elements intersect, the whole first element should be under second element except axis (each element has an axis inside itself). Axis of first element should be over axis of second element. I suppose it's impossible in existing  architecture.

Comment: The axis of the back-element should be put in the adorner layer in would therefor be above the front-element. the axis is a different element and therefor this is perfect place for adorner layer usage. I'm assuming he has access to it. If it's a control he can't manipulate then it won't work obviously.

Comment: So what? Let's rely that @Aks couldn't modify Chart source code. Then he could create Adorner, extract axis element with LogicalThreeHelper/VisualTreeHelper and apply Adorner to this  element. But Adorner does not render target element itself, adorner renders just additional data! Even if we imagine that adorner is able to render axis, how do suppose to control rendering order? What axis will end up at front (will be rendered last)? On the other hand if @Aks could modify Chart source code, I'd reccomend him to write custom rendering instead of using adorners.